# How to avoid cyclic dependencies without battling with the compiler in svelte?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, svelte

I was reading the doc, and after tweaking its sample code, I managed to get compiler barked at me about cyclic dependencies like this:

```
<script>
    let count = 0;
    $: double = count * 2;

    $: if (double >= 20) {
        alert(`count is dangerously high!`);
        count = 9;
    }

    function handleClick() {
        count += 1;
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {count} {count === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

I asked on discord how to fix it, and people suggested that I should hide the dependencies from the compiler like this:

```
<script>
    let count = 0;
    $: double = count * 2;

    function resetCount() {
        count = 9;
    }

    $: if (double >= 20) {
        alert(`count is dangerously high!`);
        resetCount();
    }

    function handleClick() {
        count += 1;
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {count} {count === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

It works, but I got a couple questions:

1. Battling with the compiler doesn't sound right to me, is there any other better ways to fix this?
2. A more general question is that does cyclic dependencies happen quite often to people who have written large amount of svelte code? Is it normal or it usually signals a bad design?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The answer from @morphyish sort-of provides a fix, because as they stated:

> a reactive statement can't trigger itself

However, I see that as somewhat of a technicality, and still see the provided solution as conceptually having a cyclic dependency: we still have `count -> double -> count -> ...`.

And because we've bypassed this cyclic dependency warning by merging the statements into a single reactive block, we've actually also introduced a bug:

[image]

This bug occurs because the `double` value is set to `10 * 2` = 20 at the beginning of the reactive block, then `count` is set to `9` within the if-statement, but then `double` is not set back to `9 * 2 = 18` because the reactive block doesn't trigger again.

My suggestion in this, and similar cases would be to re-evaluate what your dependencies actually are in order to remove these cycles:

```
double = count * 2;
```

^ So `double` depends on `count`, that one's easy.

```
if (double >= 20) {
  alert('count is dangerously high!');
  count = 9;
}
```

^ At first glance it might seem like our count-reset logic depends on `double`, but seeing as we've already established that `double` depends on `count` – and this block is ultimately concerned with `count` – this logic really depends on `count` **not** `double`.

So in my view, the best solution would be to modify the conditional to match the actual dependency:

```
<script>
    let count = 0;
    $: double = count * 2;

    $: if (count >= 10) {
        alert(`count is dangerously high!`);
        count = 9;
    }

    function handleClick() {
        count += 1;
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {count} {count === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could fix this issue by organizing your code slightly differently:

```
<script>
    let count = 0;
    let double;
    $: {
       double = count * 2;
       if (double >= 20) {
        alert(`count is dangerously high!`);
        count = 9;
       }
    }

    function handleClick() {
        count += 1;
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {count} {count === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

You can group reactive statements together using `{}` with a small caveat: Svelte won't automatically write the variable declaration as it would otherwise.

I've never run into this issue before, but in your case it looks like both statement are dependent on `count` being updated, albeit indirectly for the second one. So it makes sense to actually group them into a single statement.

It also solves your issue as a reactive statement can't trigger itself.

However it means that if you want to also update `double` you would need to do it explicitly.